# Meaning of an "instance of a database"

Tags: database

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_(semantics)#Computer_science

> In computer science, some database textbooks use the term 'intension' to refer to the schema of a database, and 'extension' to refer to **particular instances of a database**.

does a "particular instance of a database" mean

- a database,
  or
- a tuple of a relational database, for a relational database viewed as a relation in mathematics?

Thanks.

Comment: can you name an example of such a textbook?

Comment: @gnat: I don't know. the quote is from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_(semantics)#Computer_science

Answer (score 6):

The way that I've seen "instance" used, at least in business contexts, is a *deployment* of a given database (schema + data). For example, I might say "this report is dangerous, because it is going against the master instance and may be slow; it should use the reporting instance." Or you might have "five instances of the testing database" on your staging servers.

Answer (score 5):

I have seen that term mostly used in an Oracle context. From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/startup.htm#CNCPT005):

> A database instance is a set of memory structures that manage database
>   files. A database is a set of physical files on disk created by the
>   CREATE DATABASE statement. The instance manages its associated data
>   and serves the users of the database.

So in that context, the term **database** means simply the files holding the schema and the actual data, while **database instance** refers to the server processes and the related memory structures which actually manage those files.

Microsoft, for example, uses the term "instance" for ["a copy of the sqlservr.exe executable that runs as an operating system service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231298.aspx)", so the meaning is very similar, though in that context one instance can manage multiple databases.

I am not sure if other vendors use the terms exactly in one of the above meanings, but I would not be too surprised.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a database instance describes a complete database environment, including the `RDBMS` software, table structure, stored procedures and other functionality. Database administrators might create multiple instances of the same database for different purposes.